# Common elements in two list without complete traversal

Tags: java

How can I find common elements in two lists without actually going through each and every elements in both the lists? I mean without using the usual traversal method in which we tend to compare one element with the whole list.

Additional details:

1.the lists are sorted

2.want to find common elements by traversing least number of elements in the second list

Comment: `in two lists with actually going through` do you mean `without actually going through` what ever method you use, worst case scenario, you still need to traverse each list at least once to verify whether or not an element is present.

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

List<Integer> list2= new ArrayList<Integer>();

List<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<Integer>(list2);

list3.retainAll(list1);
```

`list3` will have only common elements of `list1` and `list2`.

This is just one optimized library method which obviously traverses the lists.

Answer (score 2):

[`list.retainAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

Note: It will traverse under the cover, you can't do it without traversal

Comment: actually both `List` and `Set` have method `retailAll()`, so no need to convert.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean you don't want to traverse the second list entirely for every element in the first list.

One way would be to sort both lists and then read through them at the same time, advancing on or other iterator for a mismatch and both for a match.

An alternative would be to sort one list and then binary search it for every element in the other.

Comment: sorting requires to traverse all the list

Comment: The question's not well written; I am assuming they want to avoid a O(n^2) algorithm. Also, it may be that one or both lists are already sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking for an O(n) solution, instead of the naive O(n^2) solution of traversing the lists in an outer and inner loop.

One way would be to traverse one of the lists and put its elements in a hash table. Then, traverse the other list and for each element, check if the element exists in the hash table. This would be an O(n) solution, but space consuming of course.